# IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.0 becomes non editable and requires restart

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.0 (Ultimate edition)
Java 1.8, 1.6
Scala 2.11

We are working on a project which has several modules most of them are Java and one of the modules is in scala.

For some odd reason IDE becomes non editable (i.e) I can't modify any files, though I can click and navigate between files.

Its so annoying that we've to restart the whole IDE or mutilple IDEs in case we have multiple projects opened on different IDE windows.

Comment: It looks like Issue for [IDEA bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) not like a question

Comment: Sure I'll raise it there, thanks for the pointers.

Comment: I've noticed similar behavior with IntelliJ.  I may have seen it with v13 but it seems much more prevalent with 14.   Sometimes it seems to clear itself up and other times I have to restart like you do to restore sanity.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this, I think its due to accidentally changing the edit mode,

at the bottom right corner there is a small lock icon, if you click that it will toggle readonly and editable.

[image: Location of the Lock Icon]

Comment: I'll mark your answer as the right one, once I'm able reproduce and fix the issue. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was the accidentally turned on Vim emulator (found the answer [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/user_images/At0IkbuasQLtIK-6IcGX2A.png)). Untick `Tools -> Vim Emulator`.

Here's the image from the original thread:

[image]